# Best practice to generate token for email action

Tags: customization, links

I need to make a custom link to confirm order from user by email.
This is the basic code :

```
private static function get_confirmation_link( int $recipient_id, array $params = null ){
    return home_url(sprintf( '?foo=%1$s&var1=%2$s&var2=%3$s&token=%4$s',
            '1',
            $recipient_id,
            $params['order-id'],
            $params['token'] //<-- how I generate this ?
        )
    );
}
```

The goal is check the token after the user click on the link in his email to be sure he´s the right person who does this action (confirm his order).

Simple question : what is the best practice to generate token used in a link ?

Should I use `wp_generate_user_request_key()` and `wp_send_user_request()` ?
If I should not use these functions, I know 2 ways to store the token :

1. as order post meta_data
2. as transient

What could be the best storage, I mean the way more Wordpress compliant ?

Comment: what is the token for and how are you processing it? Note that `sprintf` won't sanitise or encode the URL parameters, so it is not the right function to use, and `home_url` isn't always `/`, `site_url` would be more appropriate

Comment: @TomJNowell, my idea was to use a token to be sure it´sthe right client who confirms his order (home made custom post type). Thanks for your others notices.

Comment: How do you intend to validate the token that's generated once the user has clicked on the link? Are you storing the token somewhere? This is important to know, if you do not have an answer or don't know, we would also need to know that too. Also keep in mind this isn't a discussion forum so you need to be able to mark an answer as the canonical authoritative answer that answers this specific question for all people

Comment: @TomJNowell, Yes, I would like to validate the token from url before confirm the order. The token storage is a part of my question relative to best practice. I would like to know if there is a common WP way to do this or if I choose a way to do this.

Comment: I have done something similar building invite tokens for registrants, I used a combination of `sessionID-teamID-tokenslot-random5characterstring` to generate the tokens, but because I was anticipating a large, large number of tokens to be generated over time, I put them all in a separate custom table.  In your case I think you'd be best off putting it into the post Order meta data.  Add it as 'postmeta' and then validate from there.